# jquery hidden left right arrow when scrollLeft to the end

Tags: jquery

jquery hidden left right arrow when scrollLeft to the end?

Just do it like `$(.left-arrow).css({'display': 'none'});

all the code here. Thanks.

http://jsfiddle.net/bNHrL/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this, basicly I've just added a hide and show of the two links:

[live version](http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/a4uxs/)

You can of course style it as you like (for instance make the links disabled). Also you could add a init to check if you start all the way to the left / right and act upon it.

Comment: excuse me, I am back late. A little bug, when the slider is loading, the defult `li` is the first, so the left arrow should be hidden yet.

Answer (score 0):

The way I've seen this done is to add a CSS class to hide your arrow, using either `visibility: hidden` or `display: none`, like so:

```
.hidden {
    visibility: hidden;
    /* display: none; */
}
```

The difference between these two CSS properties is that `display: none` removes the element completely from the flow of your page (i.e. it won't take up any space, as if you removed it from the page altogether). By contrast, `visibility: hidden` only makes the element invisible (i.e. it will still take up space, but won't display).

To hide or show the arrow, simply add/remove the `.hidden` class:

```
// Hide the right arrow.
$('.right-arrow').addClass("hidden");

// Show the left arrow.
$('.left-arrow').removeClass("hidden");
```

In your situation, I would use `visibility: hidden` to hide your arrows. If you used `display: none`, the row of boxes will slide over to fill the space where the arrow used to be. (Probably not what you want.)